# Что делать с назойливыми благодетелями?

Tags: обсуждение

В последнее время стало невозможно не замечать наличие какого-то благодетеля, который, не мудрствуя лукаво, раздаёт многим участникам плюсы, пачками по 4.

Основная проблема, связанная с этим - слишком раннее достижение лимита в 200реп./день, в результате которого честно заработанные плюсики уходят в ноль. После этого, разумеется, падает мотивация продолжать отвечать.

Возникает вопрос, рано или поздно этот товарищ привлечёт достаточно внимания, чтобы быть выпиленным. Массовый откат репутации будет довольно болезненным.

Что с этим делать? Как бороться и предохраняться?

Можно ли полагаться скажем на то, что при таком откате, выстрелившие вхолостую плюсы будут реанимированы?

Comment: Решение проблемы: удали свой аккаунт.

Comment: Ну это надо спросить, сколько должен дать пользователь, чтобы его плюсы не откатали потом. Там же лимит, что если пользователь дал много плюсов, то не откатывают при удалении.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, согласен. Ведь если его блокировать, то что ему мешает создать ещё пару сотен аккаунтов и с них начать лайкать опять :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а есть возможность удалить только ruSO аккаунт?

Comment: @vp_arth отправляешь письмо http://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact  и говоришь: хочу самоуничтожиться на ruso, а на enso  остаться. Всё.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не дождётесь, как говорится)

Comment: @vp_arth, что-то перечитываю и не понимаю, Вы жалуетесь на то, что кто-то вам лайкает ответы ваши? (просто уточнить =))

Comment: @Elena, Именно, ежедневно прилетает 3 пачки по 4 плюса. Подозреваю, что это автоматизировано.

Comment: @vp_arth, я так думаю Вы уже за"рались ) (без обид). Мне, например, приятно когда кто-то  так заходит  и лайкает мои топовые ответы "пачками". Возможно вы понравились человеку своими ответами или же ответы\впоросы от вас действительно хороши. Что в этом плохого?

Comment: Для того и придумали эти голоса, чтобы кто-то мог оценить ответ\вопрос, а уже "пачками" или единожды право каждого участника so\ruSO. Еще и наказывать человека за то, что ему понравилось 3-4 ответа одного участника ... абсурд! )

Comment: По человечески невозможно заходить с разных аккаунтов несколько раз в день и выдавать группе пользователей(я ведь не один такой) строго по 4 лайка. Я не против разового проявления благодарности. Но то, что под это дело заведён пул аккаунтов и действия автоматизированы - это проблема. И называется она "накрутка репутации".

Comment: Я просто вынес эту проблему на обсуждение. Решим, что ничего не нужно делать - так тому и быть.

Comment: @vp_arth, из вашего комментария я поняла, что у вас имеется фейковая стр. с которой вы себе же ставить несколько лайков! Иначе где доказательства (аргументированные) ? Я могу в день и десяток голосов отдать одному и тому же человеку за все его вопросы\ответы!

Comment: Ну правильно, давайте предлагать мне удалиться, самовыпилиться и застрелиться. Только потому что не люблю подобной халявы(она вредит положительной мотивации) и считаю её нечестной по отношению к другим участникам сообщества.

Comment: @Elena у vp_arth вроде бы такой странички нет. Возможно, кто-то другой настолько симпатизирует, что плюсует аж с четырёх учётных записей. Это нечестно, можно только с одной. Вот об этом и вопрос. )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Спасибо за сообщение! Проверил, принял меры. Эффект будет в ближайшие пару дней.

> В последнее время стало невозможно не замечать наличие какого-то благодетеля, который, не мудрствуя лукаво, раздаёт многим участникам плюсы, пачками по 4.
>
> Основная проблема, связанная с этим - слишком раннее достижение лимита в 200реп./день, в результате которого честно заработанные плюсики уходят в ноль. После этого, разумеется, падает мотивация продолжать отвечать.

С моей точки зрения, основная проблема здесь — нечестная накрутка голосов.

Про плюсики — не беспокойтесь о них. Все *честно* заработанные останутся на своём месте. Потолок в 200 репутации тоже есть у всех участников. Если вы и так заработали бы 200 очков, то вы ничего и не теряете.

Про мотивацию соглашусь. Несколько раз мне прилетало по 200 репы минут за десять. Сначала было приятно видеть зелёную кнопочку с большим числом. Потом понимал, что репутация фиктивная и в полночь превратится в тыкву. Немного досадно. Но чтобы уж совсем мотивация пропала — такого не было.

> Возникает вопрос, рано или поздно этот товарищ привлечёт достаточно внимания, чтобы быть выпиленным. Массовый откат репутации будет довольно болезненным.

Да, но что тут поделаешь. Массовый наплыв репутации — тоже нездоровое явление.

> Можно ли полагаться скажем на то, что при таком откате, выстрелившие вхолостую плюсы будут реанимированы?

Что означает «реанимированы»? Они будут удалены, точнее ограничены до стандартного «не более одного голоса от одного участника за один вопрос или ответ».

Если какие-то голоса откатываются, то репутация, насколько я помню, пересчитывается. Как-то так:

```
До отката
16 честных голосов     +160 репутации
4 фиктивных голоса     +40 репутации
4 честных голоса       +0 репутации (потолок)
ещё 1 честный голос    +0 репутации
---
итого
25 баллов рейтинга     +200 репутации

Пересчёт после отката
16 честных голосов     +160 репутации
4 честных голоса       +40 репутации
1 честный голос        +0 (потолок)
---
итого
21 балл рейтинга       +200 репутации
```

> Что с этим делать? Как бороться и предохраняться?

Сообщайте сразу, что вам кто-то ставит серийные плюсы или минусы. Если это действительно так, то мы всё равно когда-нибудь это обнаружим. Чем раньше — тем лучше.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Под "реанимированы" имелся в виду как раз пересчёт "4 честных +40". В общем, будут.

Comment: @vp_arth а, ну да. Вроде бы было так, но на 100% не уверен. Вот и проверим. ))

Comment: Можете в мой чат зайти: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52027/communication-with-the-yuri ?

Answer (score -1):

Что либо делать бесполезно. Если мы удалим его профиль или заблокируем, то что ему мешает заново создать пару сотен аккаунтов и снова начать лайкать. Разговоры вряд ли что-то принесут (по моему мнению).

Единственное, на что можно рассчитывать, так это на правило, что если пользователь повлиял на репутацию многих пользователей, то его голоса не откатывают. Но тут вопрос: сколько  пользователь должен дать репутации, чтоб его голоса не откатали?

Наш всеми любимый Благодетель, если ты это читаешь, то отпишись в чат сообщества для подальшего решения данного вопроса.

Comment: Т.е. ты считаешь, что если я накрутил себе достаточно много репутации - то наказывать меня уже не нужно? Сказал бы, что это мне напоминает, но здесь не место для политоты.

Comment: @vp_arth, ну он же не себе накручивает.. это разные вещи.

Comment: Считаю, что молчание о том, что тебе накручивают репу - идентично накручиванию самому себе. Вопрос совести, как говорится.

Comment: @vp_arth, ну откатят нам репутацию назад. Он зарегистрирует новые профиля и начнёт заново нам накручивать

Comment: Какое благородное занятие, держать кучу проксей, чтобы поплюсовать незнакомых людей. Уверен, после первого бана по IP - он забьёт на это дело.

Comment: @vp_arth, супер... а ничего что на несколько Областей Страны может быть один и тот же IP ? У меня по городу у всех один и тот же..

Comment: намекаешь, что наш благодетель тоже из Курахово? У вас общий IP? ;)

Comment: @vp_arth, кстати, не исключено. Я один раз не мог ответить из за того, что кто-то с таким же IP сидит. Я про то, что если забанить по IP, то это не навсегда ( IP динамический у многих ) и плюс ты забанишь целую область с таким же IP.

Comment: @Yuri а что там за история с одним IP на всех?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну у нас один IP на весь город. Провайдер выдаёт один на всех. При том он динамический. Я всегда этому радовался, когда меня в играх по IP банили, а через неделю я опять заходил :)

Comment: @Yuri динамический, но один (на всех) — это как? Каждую неделю город получает новый IP? ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да :) Жителям больших городов не понять

Comment: @Yuri круто! Ну я уже замечал несколько раз в инструментах модератора, что один IP бывает в истории у сотни участников. Обычно так у Киевстара.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну вот. Я же и говорю, что если банить по IP, то можно кучу невинных забанить

Comment: @Yuri так зачем по IP, можно же мирным путём решить.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я попробую написать тому человечку, который лайкает, чтобы в чат зашёл. Я с ним разговаривал уже недавно

Comment: @NickVolynkin, зайдите в мой чат, пожалуйста