# -1103 при удалении участника

Tags: обсуждение, репутация, нытьё

В справке конечно [написано](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed), что при удалении участников, не имеющих высокой репутации, все их голоса откатываются... Но потеря 1103 баллов - это как-то чересчур, не?

[image: Скриншот]

Заметил, что в списке записей четыре, а не одна:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: у тебя еще не много) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?page=1824&tab=reputation&filter=week

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, есть подозрение, что это [обещанный большой откат](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4909/178988)... Правда, его где-то обещали в течение недели сделать, а уже больше месяца прошло)

Comment: это всё я со своим [нытьём](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4909/176064) =)

Comment: @vp_arth нет, ты [тут](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36813536#36813536) ......[не причем](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36813638#36813638)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/20458/yuri?tab=reputation - _"Данная учётная запись временно заблокирована за нарушения при голосовании. Срок действия блокировки истечёт через 7 дней."_ и -1604.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, мне кажется ноги оттуда же росли)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ох, сочувствую.

Comment: просто немного затянули с удалением плюсователей (обнаружили 12-го марта, удалили сегодня), так что много плюсов откатилось.

Comment: @PashaPash сомнительно. Вчера в чате только Николасу намекнули на подозрительную активность. И после этого пошли блокировки и откаты репы из-за удаления кукол.

Comment: На самом деле через чур - это лишние 1103 баллов с чужого бота :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, главное что не со своего :)

Comment: Похоже, кое-кто со своими ботами любил всех активистов ветки HTML+CSS, кроме меня :-(

Comment: @alexolut не сомнительно. мой коммент - это не предположение, это реальное описание ситуации. С ботоводом связались еще в марте, просто ни у кого руки не доходили поудалять клонов :)

Comment: @PashaPash откормили ботов, а теперь люди темы создают на Мете. Требую объявить импичмент модератерскому составу.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, и меня) всего `-5`

Comment: @alexolut [tag:модераторский-произвол] переростает в [tag:модераторское-бездействие]

Comment: @PashaPash, интересно, ботовод хотел "как лучше" или это такой хитрый саботаж?

Comment: @avp конечно, чтобы было как лучше... только вопрос: кому?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

На [MSE есть вопрос](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/339911), разъясняющий, что это за откат репутации такой. Как я понимаю, были обнаружены несколько фиктивных (sock puppet) профилей участников, с которых производилась накрутка голосов. Для сокрытия факта накрутки производились так же и голосования по сообщениям других участников (по Вашим в том числе).

При удалении таких фиктивных профилей голоса, которые были с них сделаны, откатываются. Это мы и видим на приведённых Вами картинках.

Говорить о какой-то чрезмерности считаю здесь не уместным. Если правила были нарушены откат должен производиться в полном объёме. Более того, для Вас 1000 репы это не более 3% от общего числа и итоговое значении никак не влияет на привилегии, предоставляемые Вам на сайте. Кое у кого репутация свалилась ниже 10k и они потеряли привилегию "инструменты модератора", тут уже несколько более обидно должно быть.

При "честном" удалении аккаунта, который имеет большУю репутацию (конкретные цифры, к сожалению, не нашёл), его голоса не откатываются, но это делается вручную сотрудниками SO.

Институт репутации на сайтах SE считаю основополагающим и все обнаруженные факты неправомерного начисления репутации должны быть исправлены. Очень жду, что подобные исправления затронут и [проблемы, возникшие при миграции](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291897/339911) базы вопросов с ХешКода на StackOverflow. В частности потому, что они [затрагивают](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36117962#36117962) и менеджера нашего сообщества. А руководство, как известно, должно подавать пример.

Comment: Кое у кого, ага) Но и они не против. Закон есть закон.

Comment: @vp_arth, да ладно Вам, главное теперь что не нужно ожидать что ещё откатят. Хотя это Вы начали, вот и получили.

Comment: @Other, тор**о**питесь, где я говорил, что что-то неправильно? Всё ок.

Comment: А где я говорил что что-то неправильно? Да, в чате, но не тут.