# Как на Stack Overflow борются с накручиванием репутации?

Tags: поддержка, репутация

Рассматривая систему "репутации" на сайте Stack Overflow, я пришел к выводу, что очень легко искусственно накрутить себе сколь угодно высокую репутацию. А именно: надо зарегистрировать два аккаунта и постоянно с одного из них задавать простые вопросы, а с другого отвечать. И потом плюсовать и помечать как найденное решение свои же ответы с первого аккаунта. Таким образом можно быстро накрутить себе космическую репутацию.

Вопрос:

Предусмотрен ли на сайте Stack Overflow какой-нибудь метод борьбы с таким искусственным накручиванием репутации?

Comment: для этого есть модераторы, которым система сообщает, что два пользователя нарушают правила голосования, и они объединяются их

Comment: @Grundy А в чем же нарушение? Может так просто совпало что ответы некоторого человека (эксперта) всегда попадают в цель. Для отвода глаз можно и другие ответы плюсовать. В конце концов можно периодически менять второй аккаунт, тот  который задает вопросы.

Comment: Может и совпало :-)

Comment: А какой глобальный смысл в репутации?

Comment: @Vlad Vetrov Тут за репутацию дают разные ништяки типа меньше рекламы и право удалять чужие вопросы. Ну еще, как я понял,  можно назначить цену за ответ на важный для вас вопрос и заплатить репутацией. Хотя звучит это несколько пошловато. :-)

Comment: Если вы придумали хороший вопрос, который кому то интересен и даже сами на него ответили - вы уже получите репутацию. Если же вы будете городить простые вопросы и отвечать с другого акка, во первых вы получите не так много репутации, потому что поставить + вы сможете только один раз, а голоса одного пользователя постоянно за одного и того же проверяются и откатываются. Во вторых если вопрос-ответ окажутся некачественными вы рискуете, что сообщество их начнет минусовать. А если вопросы-ответы хороши и не дубли, то они имеют полное право на существование и нельзя сказать что репутация не заслуж

Comment: Не заплатить, а наградить. Звучит совсем иначе. А ещё можно наградить автора уже давно  существующего ответа, отдав ему за это от 50 до 500 баллов своей репутации.

Comment: Не вижу в этом ничего плохого, вы ведь вносите вклад в сообщество. Но не уверен, что понимаю, зачем создавать второй аккуаунт, ведь задавая вопросы с основного вы будете получать репутацию за вопросы.

Comment: Ладно, тогда другой способ мошенничества. Образуется группа, которая начинает плюсовать без разбора все ответы все вопросы и все комментарии. Просто так, вне зависимости от качества. У всех репутация взлетает до небес как результат гиперинфляция и девальвация репутации. :-)

Comment: @Foggy Finder За вопросы репутация гораздо меньше, чем за принятый ответ.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 я имею ввиду что вы можете задавать вопрос и самостоятельно давать на него ответ, так многие делают

Comment: Смотрю, у Вас уже второй вопрос **о сайте** задаётся не на Мете и переносится на Мету другими участниками. Пожалуйста, если у Вас возникает вопрос о работе самого сайта задавайте его на [Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @alexolut Что такое Мета? И почему нельзя спросить о накрутке счетчика на там форуме, где меня собственно и интересует накрутка счетчика?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Мета это "Stack Overflow о Stack Overflow". И это не форум. И почему бы нельзя на самом Stack Overflow -- потому что там это оффтопик. [Подробности в справке.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @pepsicoca1 потому что на основном сайте вопросы о программировании, а на Мете - вопросы о самом сайте. Тут так принято. И все сайты сети Stack Exchange так устроены.

Answer (score 14):

Совсем очевидные ловит автоматика. Но наказаний не выписывает, т. к. она довольно глупая и может вызывать ложные срабатывания. Она только откатывает голоса, показавшиеся ей подозрительными. Никаких блокировок и предупреждений.

Неочевидные находят люди. [За настолько заметные накрутки наказывают злоумышляющие стороны](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98467/this-account-is-temporarily-suspended-for-voting-irregularities). Репутация в результате наказания откатывается, как если бы "нечестных голосов" не было вовсе. Есть [прецедент](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5134/1103-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0).

[Заметить](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39823192#39823192) могут случайно, придётся очень сильно постараться, чтобы избежать подозрений. Особенно осложняется дело тем, что вопросы одного участника обычно сосредотачиваются в одной тематике, и в этой тематике могут быть свои завсегдатаи. Скажем, в метке [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) сейчас [есть весьма опытный сыщик участников-клонов](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&user=&room=22462). Будьте осторожны.

Потом, за совсем тривиальные вопросы тут легко огрести минусов. За много заминусованных вопросов можно получить автоматическую **вечную** блокировку от задавания вопросов.

Если же вы публикуете нетривиальные сообщения, стоит задаться вопросом, а не является ли такая деятельность **полезной** для SO?

> — А если спамеры научат ботов оставлять конструктивные и полезные комментарии?
> — Миссия. <s>[цензура]</s> Выполнена.
>
> [XKCD #810](https://xkcd.com/810/)

Comment: как только прочитал про сыщика - сразу понял о ком это :D

Answer (score 13):

Есть два режима борьбы с накрутками:

Автоматический - движок сайта просто откатывает голоса, полученные подряд от одного и того же участника за короткий период времени. Т.е. если вы кого-то три-четыре раза подряд плюсанете (или минусанете) - голоса откатит автоматически, в течение суток.

Полуавтоматический: движок сайта обнаруживает долгосрочные подозрительные схемы голосования - перекосы в % отданных голосов от одного участника к другому, голосование исключительно за одного и того же участника, и т.д.

Полуавтоматика просто выдает список подозрительных личностей модераторам, и те уже решают, была ли накрутка и что с ними делать. У модераторов есть доступ к дополнительным инструментам. Например, они видят совпадение активности пользователей по времени в виде хитрого таймлайна. Ну и банальный поиск совпадений по IP еще никто не отменял :)

Накрутка считается грубым нарушением, и самых наглых накрутчиков банят на неделю.

Таким образом, чтобы успешно накрутить себе репутацию, нужно:

1. Завести много аккаунтов. Не пару, а действительно много, хотя бы десяток
2. Задать под каждым таким аккаунтом много вопросов или дать пачку ответов (один вопрос, и пачка голосов за - все, вы спалились, бан)
3. Подождать, пока каждый такой аккаунт получит голоса от других участников (будете голосовать за них сами - поймают, бан)
4. Под каждым таким аккаунтом голосовать не только за свой основной аккаунт, но и за кучу других рандомных людей (за аккаунты-марионетки голосовать не стоит, легко обнаруживается, бан)
5. Сильно размазать все это по времени. Заходить с разницей в несколько часов, через разные прокси (действительно разные, а не через десяток серверов с ротацией)

При этом каждая марионетка может выдать вам только определенный % голосов. Переберете %, сработает полуавтоматика - бан.

Схема вполне рабочая, но в ней есть проблема - она подразумевает, что вы активно задаете вопросы и даете ответы в (2) ради ограниченного количества голосов в (4). Гораздо проще задать те же вопросы / дать те же ответы напрямую под своим основным аккаунтом - это принесет вам гораздо больше репутации, которая к тому же будет продолжать тикать со временем.

Т.е. накручивать можно, но эффективность накрутки будет меньше, чем у получения прямой репутации за обычные ответы на вопросы. :)

Answer (score 5):

Есть максимум очков, которые вы можете получить в день, как бы вы не старались. [Сейчас это 200 очков.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) Потому на самом деле вы не сможете получить какого-то прямо гигантского результата заведением ботов и подобным. Наконец, есть модераторы и администрация. Если ваших ботов удалят, то [вы потеряете все заработанные очки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed). Цитирую из правил:

> Репутация, приобретенная в результате мошеннических действий с голосованием, аннулируется.

По-настоящему много очков репутации можно получить только хорошими ответами и вопросами, за которые регулярно будут голосовать разные пользователи.

Отвечая на свой собственный вопрос вы будете получать репутацию и за голоса за вопрос, и за голоса за ответ, не размазывая голоса по разным регистрациям.

Comment: Двести очков в день это за сто дней (три месяца) получится 20000 очков. За эту сумму на сайте обещают райское блаженство. Регулярно меняя ботов вполне достижимая цифра. Вобщем проблема необеспеченной эмиссии репутации на сайте явно не решена.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, почему бы просто не попробовать :-) тогда сразу видно будет: решена или нет

Comment: @Grundy Я еще не настолько озабочен своей репутацией, чтобы ее искусственно накручивать. :-) Просто на этом сайте все крутится вокруг этой самой репутации. И сайт похож не на форум программистов, а на многопользовательскую игру где можно "грабить корованы". Не хватает только продажи прокаченных персонажей, брони и прочих игровых артефактов. :-)

Comment: Никто не скажет как именно сделана защита от накруток, но нет никаких сомнений что такая защита есть. Никто не скажет не потому что не может, а потому что рассказы об устройстве такой системы откроют возможности к её манипуляции. Администрация сайта в таком не заинтересована.

Comment: @sanmai, на самом деле просто собирается много статистики по юзерам, которая затем анализируется

Comment: @sanmai Ну дай-то Бог админам отловить всех читеров. :-)

Comment: Корреляции сейчас методами машинного обучения ищутся очень легко. Свечку не держал, но вряд ли у читеров есть шансы :-)

Comment: На самом деле, в день **можно** получить больше 200, поскольку ["Конкурсы, принятые ответы и бонусы за подключения к своей учетной записи других аккаунтов не ограничены дневным пределом репутации."](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: Верно, принятыми ответами можно манипулировать. Это +15 за ответ. Не забалуешь.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 "И сайт похож не на форум программистов, а на многопользовательскую игру где можно "грабить корованы"." вы правы, это не форум

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Подумайте, может это *у вас* всё крутится вокруг репутации. Может вы проецируете ваши потребности в репутации на других, а другим до репутации дела нет? Мне, например, репутация стала безразлична сразу после получения модераторских полномочий. Очки репутации на хлеб не намажешь, на счёт в банке не зачислишь.

Comment: @sanmai *Может вы проецируете ваши потребности в репутации на других, а другим до репутации дела нет?* Я бы вообще не заморачивался с репутацией, но сайт так устроен, что постоянно напоминает о репутации. То добавляет, то снимает. И вообще, все на этом сайте крутиться вокруг репутации. :-) Поэтому и возникают вопросы об адекватности модели сайта и критериев успешности на сайте.

Comment: Если на среднем форуме нет репутации и голосов, то вас же это не волнует там так, как здесь? Вы же вопросы задаёте не чтобы голоса получить, а чтобы получить ответы. Правильные ответы - самый главный критерий успеха и пользы. Это цель сайта. С ней сайт справляется, раз уж мы обсуждаем это здесь.

Answer (score 4):

Когда так пытаются сделать, потом получается вот так: [-1103 при удалении участника](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5134/178988).

А того, чей был бот в бан на месяц (если не ошибаюсь).

Comment: На неделю. Да и то пообщавшись с "нарушителем" понял, что это совсем несложно создавать марионеток и делать все эти вещи. Причём эти аккаунты не так и сложно сделать чтобы выглядели подобными "обычным". Главное по возможности разные IP и без перегибов в голосованиях.