# Снижение репутации из-за удаления вопроса автором

Tags: дефект, репутация

Сегодня захожу и случайно вижу, что получил -2 балла. Оно ерунда, но стало интересно за что же. И обнаружилась такая странность.

Некто задал вопрос. Я его отредактировал. Если кеш гугла не врет это было год назад, но это  наверное не важно. И вот спустя год этот товарищ удалил вопрос и мне понизилась репа.

Логически  (то бишь бинарно) вроде и верно - тогда получил, сейчас нет результата работы - нет и баллов.

Но мне кажется это  как-то не правильно - "забирать" ранее  полученные баллы. Работа, за которую они были выданы, проведена успешно. То есть баллы заработаны честно. А удаление постов авторами - это такая лазейка для манипуляций.

Повторю - дело не в баллах, дело в логике их подсчёта. Кмк тут есть недоработка. Для некоторых это же в некотором роде стимул "работы" на SO.

Comment: "лазейка для манипуляции" - разверните мысль, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Kromster полностью спалить тему в паблик? :) Я и так много сказал

Comment: @SeVlad да, палите. Если в репутационной системе SO есть уязвимость, общественности стоит о ней знать. Вот только что-то я не верю, что эксплуатируемая много лет система содержит такие очевидные дыры. Удивите нас :) Ну, или вы вас сами удивим, объяснив, почему об этом нет смысла беспокоиться. Как получится. А до тех пор любые обсуждения вокруг этого беспредметны, а потому бессмысленны.

Comment: @D-side если левый юзер может изменять параметры системы/другого юзера - это.. если не дыра, то средство манипуляции. Если это непонятно, тогда ой. А я большего писать не буду. И лень больше расписывать и просто не думаю что это нужно. Тем более потом опять отвечать на вопросы,  что-то доказывать и писать, писать, писать. Считаете что такая логика безупречна - ваше право.

Comment: Лень, не думаете... ок, дело ваше, просто непонятно, на что вы в итоге жалуетесь и что тут обсуждать. Кстати, ознакомьтесь с парой прелюбопытнейших прецедентов, из которых может стать понятно, какие страсти вокруг этого порой разгораются: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5134/181100 https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5849/181100

Comment: @D-side ну вот и в "страсях" яркий пример возможностей для манипулирования. Но мой "сигнал" не только (и даже не столько) об этом. Я говорю о расчётах, о незаслуженном снижении балов (в тч и возможности такого) - удалении заслуженного "заработка".

Comment: Ну как вы себе это представляете, мы должны из вас клещами тянуть что-то типа "Некто создаст 50 юзеров, запостит ими 50 ответов и дождется ваших правок по ним, а потом будет их по одному удалять ровно в полночь, нагнетая газлайтинг, ужас и панику"?