# Как устроен откат репутации при удалении вопросов системой?

Tags: поддержка, репутация, дух-сообщества, удаление-вопросов

Я уже прочитал много вопросов по поводу удаления вопросов системой и другими участниками, но все-таки не нашел ответа на свой вопрос. Сегодня ночью у меня было удалено три вопроса. Я уже не помню точно что было в тех вопроса и какой у них был рейтинг. Вероятнее всего рейтинг был нулевым и никто на них ничего не отвечал. Мне как бы погоды сильно не сделало, что эти вопросы удалены. Есть одно но. Насколько я знаю, чтобы вопрос был удален, то за него должны проголосовать другие участники с довольно большим рейтингом, либо как я теперь узнал их может удалить система. Но что мне совсем непонятно, так это почему мне докинулись балы репутации после удаления этих вопросов. Когда рейтинг не очень большой и ты трясешься на каждым балом, то каждый бал тебе очень дорог. Когда мне докинулись балы за удаление вопросов, то я подумал, что можно чтобы некоторые вопросы были удалены и у меня еще больше репутации будет))) Объясните мне, пожалуйста, что произошло, а то я не очень понимаю.

P.S. Может это удачный глюк, все починять и у меня уберут репутацию??? Хочеться верить, что это не глюк))

Comment: Скорее всего вопросы были заминусованы, вот рейтинг и откатился после удаления

Comment: Удаление свежих вопросов ведёт к откату репутации, если же вопросу полгода и более - то отката не произойдёт. Вроде так объясняли мне в чате.

Comment: мои вопросы были удалены участником Дух сообщества, если я правильно понимаю термин откат, то он значит возвращение к предыдущему значению репутации, а у меня репутация увеличилась.

Comment: [Дух удаляет плохие вопросы/ответы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293/213987), значит допустим на вопросе было -15 - и вам откатят эти -15, значит рейтинг увеличится на 15. А вот [при удалении учёток целиком](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5134/213987) результат зависит от того, как удаляли.

Comment: А вообще, если вы прочитали много вопросов про удаление, то могли бы и ссылки привести в тексте. Вы же видите блок "связанные и похожие вопросы" справа? Туда попали бы ваши ссылки и уже попали обе моих.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

На сайте есть автоматический механизм «[Дух сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%d0%94%d1%83%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0)». Он удаляет вопросы, которые имеют рейтинг ниже 0 и на которые давно нет ответов.

Подробнее: [Автоматическое удаление заброшенных вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392/181472).

У ваших вопросов было -3, -2 и -1, прошёл месяц. Вот результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А репутацию вам «вернули». За 6 минусов было -12 репы, после удаления добавилось +12.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь мне окончательно стало все понятно.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за правку. Похоже, у меня на клавиатуре кнопка ноль сломалась.