# Нужно ли удалять свои старые вопросы без ответов самостоятельно?

Tags: поддержка, удаление-вопросов, дух-сообщества

У меня есть сейчас на `StackOverflow на русском` 129 вопросов, часть из них без ответов и иногда в них есть комментарии. Несколько дней тому я попал в электронные руки пользователя `Дух сообщества`, который удалил несколько моих старых нулевых или минусовых вопросов. Более подробная информация здесь - [Как устроен откат репутации при удалении вопросов системой?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7725/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9).

И вот собственно у меня возник вопрос - может пользователю нужно самому удалять свои кривые и тупые вопросы, или не забирать работу у электронного помощника модераторов?

Comment: Пусть потеет машина: https://www.artlebedev.ru/best/ui/humaneness/

Comment: тогда закономерный вопрос - машина точно удалит все мои нулевые вопросы, или какие-то может пропустить? потому-что судя по отзывам других пользователе этот робот непредсказуемый )

Comment: Алгоритмы удаления вопросов известны и приведены в справке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет не нужно. Дух сам удалит всё, что посчитает нужным.