# Почему мои безответные вопросы не попадают под проверку системы для удаления

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, дух-сообщества

Несколько месяцев тому я узнал что на сайте есть механизм для удаления заброшенных вопросов. Сейчас у меня подкопилось немного вопросов, и собственно стало интересно когда и с какой периодичностью `Дух` проводит чистку. И как это все происходит если не секрет, как он их мониторит например. Есть кучи вопросов связанных с действиями этого пользователя, но мне не очень понятно с какой частотой, в какой период происходит чистка вопросов.

### UPDATE

вопрос не в том как работает проверка и удаление, а в том почему до меня например она не доходит, вернее до моих вопросов. Мои вопросы были удалены только один раз и больше их никто не трогал а они копятся.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Ну это странный вопрос в таком случае — не удаляются, потому что не выполняется какое-то из условий для удаления.

Comment: вот например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876780/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-navigation-drawer-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5 - здесь ему больше 30 дней, не закрыт и если я правильно понимаю то он должен быть удален, но он все-равно есть)

Comment: В частности, насколько я вижу, сейчас у вас нет неудаленных вопросов с рейтингом -1 или менее

Comment: теперь я вас не очень понимаю)) можете уточнить свой последний комментарий? если я правильно понимаю, то если у вопроса даже 0 в рейтинге и он без ответов и комментов, то он удаляется

Comment: По конкретно этому вопросу условие для удаления по истечении 30 дней не выполняется, если всё будет продолжаться так же (вопрос не наберет рейтинга, не получит комментариев и не наберет просмотров), то он будет удален только по прошествии 365 дней

Comment: то есть если у меня есть подобные вопросы, то нужно ждать год для его удаления? а если у меня есть минусовые вопросы, то они чистятся раз в месяц?

Comment: Нет, не удаляется, почитайте предложенный дубликат, все условия там перечисленные должны выполняться **одновременно** (логическое И)

Comment: Поправил оригинальный вопрос, если ваш вопрос исчерпан — предлагаю дозакрыть его.

Comment: да я уже отправил запрос) спасибо за помощь)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko автор вопроса может закрыть его дубликатом принудительно. Там кнопка появляется сверху.

Comment: @alexolut, мне на данный момент нужно предпринимать какие-то действия?

Comment: Уже нет. Совет на будущее.

Comment: На всякий случай скажу: автор вопроса может сам удалить свои вопросы, по которым нет ответов (под вопросом ищите кнопку «удалить»). Т.е. если вопросы копятся, то их можно вычистить. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions

Comment: @defaultlocale, я знаю про эту возможность, но я недавно спрашивал здесь, нужно ли самостоятельно чистить вопросы, и мне сказали что нет, пусть система чистит

Comment: Вы [про это](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7745/)? Я понимаю ответ модератора как: «Необязательно чистить вопросы. Старые вопросы не мешают *системе*». В то же время если вопрос уже неактуален для *Вас лично*, то Вы имеете полное право его удалить.

Comment: @defaultlocale, как-то не так понимаешь...