# Какой рекорд снятия репутации?

Tags: обсуждение, репутация

Я конечно понимаю, что когда участник удаляется, то у всех репа снимается, но лично для меня это перебор:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Безусловно, против системы не попрёшь, и, вероятнее всего, никаких откатов не будет. А посему вопрос - какой рекорд?)

Видел [такой вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7725/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9), но не уверен что моё мне вернётся, могу ошибаться.

Comment: У нас или вообще? Бывает, что счёт на тысячи репутации идёт)

Comment: Эк как тряхнуло в этот раз.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, просто немного неприятненько)) конечно тут система своя работает и все такое) но отвечание на вопросы порой требует сил и энергии а теперь получается что они потрачены впустую :(

Comment: @Andrew ваши ответы помогли людям, значит не впустую.

Comment: @Andrew, почему впустую? Удалили же пользователя, а не ответы

Comment: [-1103 и больше](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5134/178988), но это было удаление чьих-то ботов для накрутки.

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда у меня еще не все так плохо :)

Comment: @Grundy, оно конечно да, но с этим я столкнулся впервые в таком кол-ве, поэтому нужно просто смирится и работать над собой :)

Comment: А мне интересно, что значит *крайне высокая репутация*? :) Смотрим - "*Отмена голосов происходит при удалении любого пользователя, кроме тех, кто имеет **крайне высокую репутацию***."

Comment: @Harry, это кстати хороший вопрос)) значит у меня не крайне высокая репа)) мы нашли отправную точку)

Comment: Это относится не к тем, у кого снимают, а к тем, *из-за удаления кого* снимают.

Comment: @Harry, ааа, я понял теперь))

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Из того, что знаю, был случай со снятием `33894` единиц репутации. У [этого участника](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9003/amwhy?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=48).

> [image: Потеря репутации]

Comment: Как пользователь может дать не кратное 2/5/10 количество репутации?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, плюс за вопрос дает 5, минус за ответ/вопрос дает -2, в сумме 3, например,

Comment: Grundy всё знает! :-)

Comment: @Grundy, неактуальненько - 5 должны были ретроспективно пересчитать. Получается, должно быть чётное число.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, голос против ответа вычитает балл у голосующего. Возможно, этот пользователь голосовал против удалённого.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не понял логику :-) смотри - ты ставишь плюс вопросу и минус ответу -  в итоге у пользователя рейтинг меняется на 3 пункта

Comment: @Grundy, плюс вопросу даёт 10, а не 5.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, о, проще. Я про принятые ответы с +15 забыл.

Comment: @Qwertiy, 10 - это плюс ответу. Хотя да, возможно что-то меняли не давно

Comment: @Grundy, для тех, кто всё проспал: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9753/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy А что насчёт этих слов: `"Отмена голосов происходит при удалении любого пользователя, кроме тех, кто имеет крайне высокую репутацию"`? Описано [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed). Юзер дал 33 тысячи баллов другому, этого мало?

Comment: @AivanF. Harry же ответил "Это относится не к тем, у кого снимают, а к тем, из-за удаления кого снимают. "