# Почему стоит ограничение на количество голосов?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Я понимаю, если ограничение на отрицательные голоса. Чтобы хулиганы не заминусовали всех. А вот на положительные?

Comment: Чтобы не накрутили?

Comment: @Антон, репутацию :)

Comment: @Антон Вероятно, уточнить у Николаса.

Comment: Чтобы хулиганы не заплюсовали всех.

Comment: @defaultlocale А что, шутки шутками, а было такое дело, кто-то накрутил и репа поднялось, а потом система это дело раскусила и у всех репа посыпалась. Обидно, хорошо меня это не затронуло. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10556/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4-%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8?cb=1